# Running psexec on Powershell

Tags: powershell-ise

I am trying to run a psexec command on Powershell. I have ran this line on Windows Command Processor and it worked.

```
$computers = gc "C:\temp\scripts\computers.txt" 
foreach ($computer in $computers) 
{
    if (test-Connection -Cn $computer -quiet) {
         & C:\temp\sysinternals\psexec.exe \\$computer "C:\Temp\CMA4.5\frminst.exe/forceuninstall/silent"
    }else {  
    "$computer is not online"
    } 
}
```

This is the error i am getting:

```
psexec.exe : At C:\temp\Scripts\CopyFiles.ps1:19 char:9
+         & C:\temp\sysinternals\psexec.exe \\$computer "C:\Temp\CMA4.5\frminst.ex ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

PsExec v1.94 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2008 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
The system cannot find the path specified.
Connecting to bdp00051291... 
Starting PsExec service on bdp00051291...   
Connecting with PsExec service on bdp00051291...
Starting C:\Temp\CMA4.5\frminst.exe/forceuninstall/silent on bdp00051291...
PsExec could not start C:\Temp\CMA4.5\frminst.exe/forceuninstall/silent on bdp00051291:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing arguments to `PsExec` this way:

```powershell
$computers = gc "C:\temp\scripts\computers.txt" 
foreach ($computer in $computers) 
{
    if (test-Connection -Cn $computer -quiet) {
         & 'C:\temp\sysinternals\psexec.exe' @("\\$computer", 'C:\Temp\CMA4.5\frminst.exe', '/forceuninstall', '/silent')
    }else {  
    "$computer is not online"
    } 
}
```

It's a PowerShell secret. If you specify an array of values, it will automatically expand them into separate parameters. In 99.99% of cases this will work and save you from the ugly string concatenation and messing with quotes.

You can read more about passing arguments from PowerShell to the external executables in this comprehensive article: [PowerShell and external commands done right](http://edgylogic.com/blog/powershell-and-external-commands-done-right/).

Comment: You're welcome. I've updated my answer, so you can actually understand why this works ;).